# iOS: auto-repair unreliable/malfunctioning Wi-Fi connection?

Tags: ios, network, wifi, ios-appstore

All too often, iOS fails to automatically detect and repair faulty/unreliable Wi-Fi connections, which means I have to go into settings and manually reset it. Incredibly annoying and downright stupid.

Most of the time the fix is no more than manually reconnecting. You'd think that this would be automatic, especially with auto-join enabled. Other times I have to manually connect to another hotspot that was already on auto-join (which means that the auto-join feature is broken, low-quality, or failed).

Other times, a Wi-Fi connection stops responding and the Wi-Fi indicator on the iOS device fails to indicate that (access available to hotspot and no internet access available).

I'd like a configuration or utility (can be a third-party tool) that auto-repairs the Wi-Fi connection.

Requirements:

- Detect spotty access and intermittent outages on Wi-Fi hotspot; automatically reconnect to hotspots marked as auto-join without any input from the user.
- Link, network, and transport layer monitoring and profiling to detect errors and failed/unreliable connections.
- Automatically drop low-quality hotspots (those that drop many packets, lack proper internet access, or often fail to respond for any reason) and connect to higher-quality hotspots without input from the end-user.
- If a Wi-Fi hotspot goes out or becomes unreliable, it should automatically switch to another auto-join hotspot.
- Round-robin poll-and-connect for multiple failed hotspots: Maintain a list of auto-join hotspots and repeatedly attempt to join each one in turn. Make every effort so the end-user doesn't have to manually go into settings and do what should have been automated from the beginning.
- (Bonus - no idea if this can be done in iOS) Automatically monitor failed connections/timeouts and launch connection auto-repair on failed connection.
- (Bonus) Parallel reconnect. When the iOS device loses its Wi-Fi connection, make connection attempts on all auto-join hotspots in range (in parallel) and associate with the first one that accepts.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to configure your wifi settings without jailbreaking and installing a non-approved third-party application. By default applications on iOS devices are not granted access to configure wifi settings. Sorry.